# Common AsyncTask for Multiple Adapter Update List Item

Tags: android, interface, android-asynctask, network-programming, adapter

I'm new in Android and I have following code that shows the list of item in Adapter.

I have Four Different Adapter from where I am calling one comman **`AsyncTask`** to update Result. I have implemented one **Interface** `ApiResponse` and overrides `apiResponseProcessing()` to get result.

In Item of List **"Add to Cart"** Button Added in every row. **OnClick** of that button I am requesting to server. On Success of that response i want to update Button with "Added To Cart".

I have question How to update that string which is binded in `onBindViewHolder()`. **I am getting success in that method but dont know how to update clicked Button from that method.**

**Here's my Adapter**

```
/**
 * Adapter
 **/

public class AlbumPhotoDetailAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumPhotoDetailAdapter.ViewHolder> implements ApiResponse {

    private final ArrayList<Photo> mValues;
    Album album;
    private Activity mContext;
    private int mMemberId;

    public AlbumPhotoDetailAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Photo> items) {
        mValues = items;
        this.mContext = context;
        mMemberId = MemberPreference.getMemberId(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.album_photo_detail_sub_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Photo photo = mValues.get(position);

        /**
         * Album Owner Name
         */
        String mOwnerName = photo.getOwnerName();
        String mOwnerProfilePic = photo.getOwnerImage();
        String mDateTime = photo.getDatetime();
        String mPrice = String.valueOf(photo.getPrice());

        /**
         * Price String
         */
        String priceStr = String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.string_dollar_price), mPrice);
        holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailPhotoPrice.setText(priceStr);

        /**
         * Main Image
         */
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(photo.getLink())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                .transform(new ImageTransformation(holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubMainImage))
                .into(holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubMainImage);

        /**
         *  Owner Name and Profile Pic
         */
        holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerNameTextView.setText(mOwnerName);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mOwnerProfilePic)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                .resize(100, 100)
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerImage);

        mDateTime = mDateTime != null ? DateUtils.getNiceTime(mDateTime) : "----";
        holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerPostedTimeTextView.setText(mDateTime);       

        // Photo Add to cart.
        holder.mAddToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(mContext)) {
                    new BackgroundAsyncTask(mContext, (ApiResponse) mContext, mMemberId, photo.getId()).execute();
                } else {
                    DailyStudio.noInternetConnectionToast(mContext);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    } 

    @Override
    public void apiResponseProcessing(String response) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Api Response : "+response);
        if(response.equals(Fields.JSON_SUCCESS)) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * View Holder
     */
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final View mView;

        private ImageView mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerImage;
    private ImageView mAlbumPhotoDetailSubMainImage;
        private TextView mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerNameTextView;
        private TextView mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerPostedTimeTextView;     
        private TextView mAlbumPhotoDetailPhotoPrice;
        private TextView mAlbumPhotoDetailSubDescription;
        private Button mAddToCartButton;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;

            mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_sub_owner_image);
        mAlbumPhotoDetailSubMainImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_sub_main_image);          
        mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_sub_owner_name_text_view);
            mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerPostedTimeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_sub_owner_posted_time_text_view);
            mAlbumPhotoDetailPhotoPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_photo_price);
            mAlbumPhotoDetailSubDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_sub_description);
            mAddToCartButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.album_photo_detail_photo_add_to_cart_button);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's my Interface**

```
/**
* Interface..
*/

public interface ApiResponse {

    public void apiResponseProcessing(String response);

}
```

**Here's my Background AsyncTask**

```
/**
* Background AsyncTask...
*/

public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private String accessToken;
    private int memberId;
    private int photoId;
    private ApiResponse objIBaseApi;

    public BackgroundAsyncTask(Context context, ApiResponse apiResponse, int memberId, int photoId) {
        this.context = context;
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.photoId = photoId;
        accessToken = MemberPreference.getAccessToken(context);
        this.objIBaseApi = apiResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        JSONObject json = JSONParser.addToCartPhoto(accessToken, memberId, photoId);

        if(json != null) {
            Log.i(TAG,"First Json : "+json.toString());
            try {
                if (json.getString(Fields.RESULT).equalsIgnoreCase(Fields.JSON_SUCCESS)) {
                    return Fields.JSON_SUCCESS;
                } else if(json.getString(Fields.JSON_ERROR).equalsIgnoreCase(Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) {
                    String refreshToken = MemberPreference.getRefreshToken(context);

                    JSONObject newJSONObject = JSONParser.loginMemberWithRefreshToken(refreshToken, Integer.toString(memberId));

                    if(newJSONObject != null) {
                        if(newJSONObject.getString(Fields.JSON_ERROR).equalsIgnoreCase(Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) {
                            return Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
                        } else {
                            return Fields.JSON_SUCCESS;
                        }
                    } else
                        return Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;

                } else {
                    return Fields.JSON_ERROR;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return Fields.JSON_ERROR;
            }
        }
        return Fields.JSON_ERROR;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        objIBaseApi.apiResponseProcessing(result);

    }
}
```

Is there any solution or better way to do like this?

Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can keep one flag isAddedToCart variable in you bean class which you are using in your adapter(Photo). Now just pass the position in your asynctask once user click on "add to cart" button. On getting the successful you just need to find the bean from the list of bean you passed in adapter and change the flag isAddedToCart to true and notify your adapter thats it. Here is the code snippet:-

**Photo Class**

```
public class Photo{
private boolean isAddedToCart;

public void setAddedTOCart(boolean isAdded){
   isAddedToCart = isAdded;
}
public boolean isAddedToCart(){
   return isAddedToCart;
}

}
```

**AlbumPhotoDetailAdapter onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Photo photo = mValues.get(position);

    /**
     * Album Owner Name
     */
    String mOwnerName = photo.getOwnerName();
    String mOwnerProfilePic = photo.getOwnerImage();
    String mDateTime = photo.getDatetime();
    String mPrice = String.valueOf(photo.getPrice());
    String isAdded = photo.isAddedToCart();

    /**
     * Price String
     */
    String priceStr = String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.string_dollar_price), mPrice);
    holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailPhotoPrice.setText(priceStr);

    /**
     * Main Image
     */
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(photo.getLink())
            .error(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
            .transform(new ImageTransformation(holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubMainImage))
            .into(holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubMainImage);

    /**
     *  Owner Name and Profile Pic
     */
    holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerNameTextView.setText(mOwnerName);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mOwnerProfilePic)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
            .resize(100, 100)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .into(holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerImage);

    mDateTime = mDateTime != null ? DateUtils.getNiceTime(mDateTime) : "----";
    holder.mAlbumPhotoDetailSubOwnerPostedTimeTextView.setText(mDateTime);       
if(isAdded){
   holder.mAddToCartButton.setText("Added TO Cart");
}else{
   holder.mAddToCartButton.setText("Add TO Cart");    
}
    // Photo Add to cart.
    holder.mAddToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(mContext)) {
                new BackgroundAsyncTask(mContext, (ApiResponse) mContext, mMemberId, photo.getId(),position).execute();
            } else {
                DailyStudio.noInternetConnectionToast(mContext);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**your Interface**

```
public interface ApiResponse {
     public void apiResponseProcessing(String response,int position);
}
```

**Your Adapter apiResponceProcessing()**

```
@Override
public void apiResponseProcessing(String response,int position) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Api Response : "+response);
    if(response.equals(Fields.JSON_SUCCESS)) {
        mValues.get(position).setAddedTOCart(true);
        notifyDataSetChange();
    }
}
```

And finally your
**BackgroundAsyncTask**

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private Context context;
private String accessToken;
private int memberId;
private int photoId; 
private int mPosition;
private ApiResponse objIBaseApi;

public BackgroundAsyncTask(Context context, ApiResponse apiResponse, int memberId, int photoId,int position) {
    this.context = context;
    this.memberId = memberId;
    this.photoId = photoId;
    accessToken = MemberPreference.getAccessToken(context);
    this.objIBaseApi = apiResponse;
    this.mPosition = position;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    JSONObject json = JSONParser.addToCartPhoto(accessToken, memberId, photoId);

    if(json != null) {
        Log.i(TAG,"First Json : "+json.toString());
        try {
            if (json.getString(Fields.RESULT).equalsIgnoreCase(Fields.JSON_SUCCESS)) {
                return Fields.JSON_SUCCESS;
            } else if(json.getString(Fields.JSON_ERROR).equalsIgnoreCase(Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) {
                String refreshToken = MemberPreference.getRefreshToken(context);

                JSONObject newJSONObject = JSONParser.loginMemberWithRefreshToken(refreshToken, Integer.toString(memberId));

                if(newJSONObject != null) {
                    if(newJSONObject.getString(Fields.JSON_ERROR).equalsIgnoreCase(Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) {
                        return Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
                    } else {
                        return Fields.JSON_SUCCESS;
                    }
                } else
                    return Fields.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;

            } else {
                return Fields.JSON_ERROR;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Fields.JSON_ERROR;
        }
    }
    return Fields.JSON_ERROR;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    objIBaseApi.apiResponseProcessing(result,mPosition);

}
```

}

Comment: thanks praween nice answer but call BackgroundAsyncTask  like @georg answer

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in my opinion adapter should not care about network request. But 
giving an answer in substance, you can try pass anonymous class for your apiResponseProcessing in same manner as you create OnClickListener for your button. It can look like this:

```
holder.mAddToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(mContext)) {
                new BackgroundAsyncTask(
                    mContext, 
                    new ApiResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void apiResponseProcessing(String response) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"Api Response : "+response);
                            if(response.equals(Fields.JSON_SUCCESS)) {
                                // Here you can access you holder till it final 
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    mMemberId, 
                    photo.getId()).execute();
            } else {
                DailyStudio.noInternetConnectionToast(mContext);
            }
        }
});
```

But code like this looks messy and spaghetti. As i say at the beginning there are exist at least one different approach to handle changes for buttons inside listview/recivleview. I use method, where adapter only care about building interface with given data and delegate buttons clicks to someone else (in most cases activity that contains listview). An easy way notify activity about button click is Bus messaging pattern. I use [Otto event library](http://square.github.io/otto/). When delegate receive notification about button click, it can initiate data changing according current task and then initiate listview reloading or partial update only required rows.

Additional comments

> Try to write beautiful code. Constructor AlbumPhotoDetailAdapter has different syntax to assign instance variables. One with **this** keyword and other without. Usually you should use one way.

```
public AlbumPhotoDetailAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Photo> items) {
    this.values = items;
    this.context = context;
    this.memberId = MemberPreference.getMemberId(context);
}
```

> **album** instance variable have no  access modifiers indication. You should know, that in java programming language [omitting access specifiers is not the same as private modifier](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/access_specifiers.html).

Comment: thanks @georg for your awesome answer but can u elaborate how can i use Otto event library specially in my case. i read doc and try to understand it but i can,t understand

Comment: @mansukh-ahir this is topic not for comment size. In short: Bus messaging pattern allow communication between objects that "placed" far away from each other or has "one to many" or "many to many" relations, like in case of activity want know about buttons action inside listview. Otto allow you post notification with parameters (like mMemberId and photoId) to the world when button clicked,activity can handle this event, send network requests, manage ui. Helpful singlton [BusProvider](https://github.com/square/otto/blob/master/otto-sample/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/sample/BusProvider.java)